# Unresolved dependencies with GearVRf : backend-debug

Tags: android, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I just went through the GearVRf setup instructions ([here](http://www.gearvrf.org/bin/view/GearVRfDeveloperGuide/GearVRfDevGuide200Start#BuildRunApp)), and trying to get the demo/sample applications to compile. The framework compiles fine, but when I open a project and build it, I get:

```
Unresolved dependencies
Error:Failed to resolve: :backend-debug:
```

This happens for any demo I choose,and is all the information I am given.

Also, the 'Android Support Repository' is installed, if that is your first guess.

Any suggestions on either getting more information about the problem, or how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the necessary dependency (backend-debug.arr) is in the GearVRf-Demos directory.

If you move the GearVRf-Demos directory INSIDE the "GearVRf" directory, everything magically works.

Giving you: "..\GearVRf\GearVRf-Demos\gearvrf-libs"